# What is the purpose of adopting latest App + Web property when a project can be created via Firebase console?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

So Google Analytics for Apps is sunsetting October 2019 and has this notice posted:

> Notice - Immediate Action required! This property receives data from
>   our legacy app analytics SDK, which we will begin sunsetting on
>   October 31, 2019. To continue using our product, **adopt our latest App
>   + Web property**, which utilizes Google Analytics for Firebase SDK. Learn more.

Its clear that code needs to migrate to GA for Firebase SDK. What's confusing is that Firebase Console has a way to add a project and GA is asking to **adopt our latest App + Web property** These 2 actions seem redundant.

Question: What is the purpose of **adopting latest App + Web property** when a project can be created via Firebase console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App+Web property allows you to combine the data from your website + app. Example, if your website servers similar functions as your app and you want to see how user behavior differ between the two OR if users are driven to/from the web/app then you're able to combine the two and easily see what the user did in the app or web before converting in the other.

When you create an "App + Web" property, it'll walk you through either creating a new firebase property or link to an existing one.

The purpose, as I've mentioned above, is to be able to combine the user behavior between the two more easily in one place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was aware of the correlation between web + data. The part about linking to existing Firebase project answered my question though. From what I understand this allows you to view Firebase analytics in GA.